# How to see how far "off" my machine learning prediction is?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I've essentially got a machine learning algorithm that has an accuracy of 20%.

This is not that high, but I would like to know how close my algorithm is on average.

So if it predicted a value of 69 and the real value in the testing-data was 68 and it had that "margin"-of-error throughout then I would be fine with using it for the purpose that I am using it for, which is filling in missing data in a data-set.

Is there some easy way to do this?

Snippet of my code:

```
def predict_score_industry(df):

    coi = ['score_teaching',
           'score_research',
           'score_citation',
           'score_int_outlook',
           ]

    not_nans = df['score_industry'].notnull()
    df_notnans = df[not_nans]

    x = np.array(df_notnans[coi])
    y = np.array(df_notnans['score_industry'])

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25)

    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

    print("score_industry: ", clf.score(x_test, y_test))

    df_nans = df.loc[~not_nans].copy()
    df_nans['score_industry'] = clf.predict(df_nans[coi])
    df.score_industry.fillna(df_nans.score_industry, inplace=True)

    return df
```

It basically takes all unfilled values and predicts them, the dataframe it reads in looks like this:

```
> print(df.info())
Data columns (total 15 columns):
university_name       2884 non-null object
country               2884 non-null object
ranking               2884 non-null int64
no_student            2884 non-null int64
no_student_p_staff    2884 non-null float64
pct_intl_student      2884 non-null float64
year                  2884 non-null int64
score_overall         2884 non-null float64
score_teaching        2884 non-null float64
score_research        2884 non-null float64
score_citation        2884 non-null float64
score_industry        2884 non-null float64
score_int_outlook     2884 non-null float64
male                  2884 non-null float64
female                2884 non-null float64
```

Comment: You cannot have "an accuracy of 20%" (or any other number), since you are in a regression setting and accuracy is only meaningful in classification ones...

Comment: Oh really? I merely printed the score of the x_test and y_test arrays. What metric is valuable to know in a regression setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer, which will hopefully help you clarify some issues...

> So I've essentially got a machine learning algorithm that has an accuracy of 20%.

Since you are in a regression setting, your score by definition cannot be the accuracy, which is only meaningful in *classification* problems.

> I merely printed the score of the x_test and y_test arrays

Yes, you have actually used the `score` method of the `LinearRegression` model in scikit-learn, which returns the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) (R^2); from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score):

> **`score`**(*X, y, sample_weight=None*)
>
> Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.
>
> The coefficient R^2 is defined as (1 - u/v), where u is the residual sum of squares ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum() and v is the
>   total sum of squares ((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum(). The best
>   possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be
>   arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected
>   value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of
>   0.0.

Arguably, the R^2 is seldomly used in machine learning settings, where the requirement is the predictive ability (it is mainly used by statisticians, where the requirement is usually the explanatory power of the model).

> What metric is valuable to know in a regression setting?

The [Mean Squared Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) (MSE) and its variants are the most commonly used metrics in regression problems. Check the scores available for regression in the scikit-learn [model evaluation module](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html).